# How to make global navigation consistent throughout main site and subsites?

Tags: 2010, navigation, sub-site

I am developing a SharePoint intranet for the company I work for. The intranet is made up of the main site and then several subsites.

I would like the Navigation to be the same on every page and in the same order (like a normal website). I have this set up on the main site without problem.

I thought that selecting **"Display the same navigation items as the parent site"** for the subsite's global navigation setting would do the trick.

The problem is that when I select that and navigate to the subsite, the subsite doesn't show up in the navigation, and is replaced by the Main site.

You can see the problem in the images below:

**Navigation on main site** (blank light blue nav item is link to main page of main site)
[image]

**Navigation on "Blog" subsite** (Now the light blue item and the second nav item are links to the same main page)
[image]

Is there any sane way to realize what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to test the OOB behavior with users before you change it. The thought is that the first item in the nav is a link to the home page of the current site, which isn't illogical. If you still want to get rid of it, you can do so via CSS. The following will hide the first tab on a publishing site:

```
.topmenudiv li.static > .menu-item,.topmenudiv li.static > .selected { display: none;} .topmenudiv li.static li.static > .menu-item,.topmenudiv li.static li.static > .selected { display: inline-block;}
```

(The above won't work for a non-publishing site).

Comment: Changed the images to more clearly reflect the navigation. So the light blue item goes to the main home page. Problem is that when I go to a sub-site, the subsite's nav item disappears and an additional nav item to the to the main homepage appears to the right

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Are you sure there's no custom css or other customizations on the page? I also have a publishing site set up with items on the top nav, and there's a blog site that's set to use the parent nav, and it works fine and does not have a duplicate as you described.